# Error [FirebaseError]: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments,

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");

// Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "____",
    authDomain: "____",
    projectId: "____"
  });
  
var db = firebase.firestore();

var datasetSymptom=[{
    "Disease" : [ "edema pulmonary" ],
    "Symptom" : "Heberden's node"
  }, {
    "Disease" : [ "cholecystitis" ],
    "Symptom" : "Murphy's sign"
  }, {
    "Disease" : [ "hemiparesis", "hypertension pulmonary", "transient ischemic attack" ],
    "Symptom" : "Stahli's line"
  }
  ]

datasetSymptom.forEach(function(obj) {
    db.collection("datasetSymptom").doc(obj.Symptom).set({
        Disease: obj.Disease
    })
});
```

I already ran the same algo on another collection with same `Disease` name as doc and array of symptoms as field. It worked fine.
Error:

```
D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:25868
            throw replaceFunctionName(e, 'doc()', 'CollectionReference.doc()');
            ^

Error [FirebaseError]: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but datasetSymptom/feels hot/feverish has 3.
    at new FirestoreError (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\←[4m@firebase←[24m\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:209:28)
    at validateDocumentPath (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\←[4m@firebase←[24m\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:19706:15)
    at doc (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\←[4m@firebase←[24m\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:22462:9)
    at CollectionReference$1.doc (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\node_modules\←[4m@firebase←[24m\firestore\dist\node-cjs\database-21da52c3-e2da0fdd.js:25864:64)
    at D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\index2x2.js:1233:37
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\react tutorial\reactnative\fyp\index2x2.js:1231:16)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'invalid-argument'←[39m,
  toString: ←[36m[Function (anonymous)]←[39m
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: and my data is much bigger than shown in the code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one or more of the objects in your array don't have a `Symptom` property. When that happens `doc(obj.Symptom)` results in a reference to an empty document, which is what causes the error.

To find the problematic array item, either check your JSON manually, or do something like this in your code:

```
datasetSymptom.forEach(function(obj, index) {
  if (obj.Symptom && object.Symptom.length) {
    db.collection("datasetSymptom").doc(obj.Symptom).set({
      Disease: obj.Disease
    })
  }
  else {
    console.error(`Found an object without a Symptom at index ${index} in the array`);
  }
});
```

Comment: 1) Please limit the number of comments you post, as this information could've been a single comment. 2) The log line you shared doesn't wsay what is wrong with the code, and it's hard to help with just "it doesn't work". Please provide specific information about the exact problem you get when you use the code in my answer. Did you debug the problem yourself already, for example by stepping through the code line by line in a debugger?

Comment: The problem was one symptom contained a '/' in its string as that is invalid in firestore so i replaced it with '-' thus that solved the issue